# Vertically align text in two columns

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, two-column

I am writing in two columns. I am trying to align the text vertically such that it does not add extra spaces. Happy for the content to be finished before the end of the page.
This is what I want:

[image: Table of contents aligned]

The class for this one is `dndbook`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,openany,nodeprecatedcode]{dndbook}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\MakeShortVerb{|}
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
  breaklines=true,
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
```

This is what I have:

[image: Table of contents not aligned]

I am using `\raggedbottom` and `extarticle` class:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,10pt]{extarticle}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, can you help us to put a complete compilable code to solve your problem?

Comment: I have added the code. The complete code is really long. I have just added the parts which I think are relevant.

Comment: It is very useful to have the relevant code deleting the packages that are not importants.

Comment: Hopefully removing `\raggedbottom` will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `twocolumn` option for the document class, consider using the multicol package (`\usepackage{multicol}`) with a single `\begin{multicol}{2}` environment surrounding the table of contents:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\pagebreak
```

(You can start another one on the next page if need be.)

See the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en).